# SQL - Select same values in column then rename them

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible in SQL to select values in a column then rename the duplicate ones? (assuming maximum of one possible duplicate only)

Let's say I have a table..

```
| id | name  | 0or1_id |
| 0  | Eddy  | 0       |
| 1  | Allan | 0       |
| 2  | Eddy  | 1       |
| 3  | Allan | 1       |
```

What query can I do to make it like this?

```
| id | name       | 0or1_id |
| 0  | Eddy       | 0       |
| 1  | Allan      | 0       |
| 2  | Eddy-copy  | 1       |
| 3  | Allan-copy | 1       |
```

Comment: ..you have tagged mysql and sql server..be specific as both are different one ...

Comment: What's the purpose behind this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to actually change the data, use `update`:

```
update t join
       (select name, count(*) as cnt, min(id) as minid
        from t
        group by name
        having cnt > 1
       ) tt
       on t.name = tt.name and t.id <> tt.minid
    set name = concat(name, '-copy');
```

If you only want a `select`, then the logic is quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in SQL Server..

```
select id , name ,0or1_id from (
select id , name ,0or1_id ,row_number() over (partition by name order by id ) as rnm
from table)z1
where rnm =1
union 
select id , name || '- Copy' as new_name ,0or1_id from (
select id , name ,0or1_id ,row_number() over (partition by name order by id ) as rnm
from table)z2
where rnm > 2
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff..agree thats why mentioned SQL Server. Didn't see the tag is changed to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ebaf/1

```
UPDATE mytable t
INNER JOIN mytable t1
ON t.name = t1.name
  AND t.id>t1.id
SET t.name = CONCAT(t.name,'-copy');
```